# Python imaplib - get uids greater than

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'm using python imaplib to synchronize imap messages with my database.
Let's say that my newest message uid in my database is 170, I'm trying to get list of newest messages (greater than 170).

```
imap_server = 'my.imap.server'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
mail.login(imap_user, imap_password)

start_message_uid = 169
if start_message_uid:
    command = "UID {}:*".format(start_message_uid)
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, command) 
else:
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL") # this returns list of all messages
```

but this command:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, command)
```

Returns ["Error in IMAP command received by server."]

Can you point what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback please

Comment: And turn on debug logging.

Comment: Maybe you need to try different commands like `fetch`. Can you paste the error message you have received.

Answer (score 2):

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'UID ' + str(start_message_uid) + ':*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your interests. I've resolved it by using:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UID", start_message_uid + ':*')
```